# Flutter Video player loading and buffering example

Tags: flutter, video, video-streaming

I am trying to understand how the flutter video player works. If I load a url to a single file mp4 video that is 20MB in file size, is the entire file downloaded before it plays? or is part of the file downloaded somehow and then more downloaded when they reach a certain way through the video (like buffering).

The video is a single file and has not be transcoded into smaller files with different bitrates.

I initialise my player like so

```
 videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(url)
          ..initialize().then((_) {
            setState(() {});
          });
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using `VideoPlayer` widget "as is" guarantee you to have a standard buffer management. This mean that if you stop the video, the plugin on background continue to load the video.

Keep attention that our API or web server support the buffering/file streaming and not only the file download, in this last case the `video_player` will start only after complete video download from server.

Answer (score 1):

1. declare

   ```
   bool isLoading = true;
   ```
2. set isloading to false in initstate on initialize controller

   ```
    videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(url)
          ..initialize().then((_) {
   setState(() {
   isLoading = false;
          });
   ```
3. in your widget

   ```
   isLoading?CircularProgressIndicator():SizedBox()
   ```